# Documentation of API for macos app in javascript?

Tags: javascript, macos, cocoa

I found it possible to write mac app in javascript from https://tylergaw.com/articles/building-osx-apps-with-js/.

Here is a sample app.

```
ObjC.import("Cocoa");

var styleMask = $.NSTitledWindowMask | $.NSClosableWindowMask | $.NSMiniaturizableWindowMask;
var window = $.NSWindow.alloc.initWithContentRectStyleMaskBackingDefer(
  $.NSMakeRect(0, 0, 400, 300),
  styleMask,
  $.NSBackingStoreBuffered,
  false
);

window.center;
window.title = "Hello world";
window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window);
```

Is there any documentation of API? What does `$` mean and how can I use it? How can I capture user input? How can I  draw UI?

Comment: Did you even read the page you posted here?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write full apps with JXA (Javascript for Automation) as stated in the JXA-cookbook:

> JavaScript for Automation is a new feature in OS X Yosemite. It lets you control applications and the operating system using JavaScript language.

Not the official documentation but you can check out [JXA-Cookbook](https://github.com/JXA-Cookbook/JXA-Cookbook/wiki) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You posted a link and obviously didn't read it.
It's all stated in the authors texts.

**Is there any documentation?**

> The [Foundation framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation) does what its name suggests. It provides the building blocks for OS X apps. The framework includes a large amount of classes and protocols. NSArray, NSURL, NSUserNotification, and so on. You may not be familiar with those classes, but their names hint at what they do. Because of its importance, you can use its classes without needing to import it in new apps. They are available by default.

**What about the dollar sign?**

> The dollar sign is your access to the Objective-C bridge. Any time you need to access 
>   an Objective-c class or constant, you use $.foo or ObjC.foo. There are a couple of 
>   other ways to use $ that I’ll cover later.

He even explaines UI. On the very page you posted...

Comment: I visited Foundation page, only to find some class definitions. I expect to know how to use them. The author shows some `NS` classes, but what is full list I can use after `$` or `ObjC` to feed my requirements? Is it a class or interface definition? If you have visited MDN doc, I expect something like that. Regarding UI, I expect more GUI components, like dropdown or sidebar if any. BTW, I tried his way of creating a `TextField` but got crashed with Script Editor.

Comment: Well, you'll have to dig through Apples documentations. I honestly doubt anyone will create another documentation just because you can bridge OBJC over Javascript. You should be able to use anything the Foundation Framework provides.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official [Apple JXA release docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/Articles/OSX10-10.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014508-CH109-SW27) the `$` is a global 'proxy' property that is used to access Objective-C methods.

It can probably be said that `$` is a shorthand for the current `Application()` object and is used to access objects defined in the app's namespace.

To draw an analogy with Applescript, `$` could be considered to be a reference to the inner scope created by a block defined by `tell application ABC..` or `tell process XYZ..`.

Moreover, `$` is the namespace into which your `import`'s go. If you import some framework for example with `ObjC.import('Cocoa')` then `$` will be the access point for the API exposed by the framework.

See also:

- [Using Objective C (ObjC) with JXA](https://github.com/JXA-Cookbook/JXA-Cookbook/wiki/Using-Objective-C-%28ObjC%29-with-JXA#the--object)